Add Gallery items programmatically inside an InnerBlock
I have created a custom block which contains WooCommerce Product info. The block is basically an InnerBlocks main component with a template that looks like this:
  const createTemplate = (
    productName,
    productDescription,
    productImages,
  ) => [
    [
      'core/columns',
      {
        verticalAlignment: 'center',
        className: 'classes',
      },
      [
        [
          'core/column',
          {
            templateLock: false,
            className: 'whatever',
          },
          [
            [
              'core/column',
              {
                templateLock: false,
                className: 'whatever',
              },
              [
                [
                  'core/gallery',
                  {
                    images: productImages,
                  },
                ],
                [
                  'core/paragraph',
                  {
                    placeholder: 'Placeholder',
                    className: 'whatever',
                  },
                ],
              ],
            ],
            [
              'core/column',
              {
                templateLock: 'all',
                className:
                  'd-flex f-column mw-60 w-100 exp-card-left-content-right-col',
              },
              [
                [
                  'core/heading',
                  {
                    placeholder: 'Title',
                    content: productName || 'Product Name',
                    className: 'whatever',
                  },
                ],
                [
                  'core/paragraph',
                  {
                    placeholder: 'Content',
                    content: productDescription || 'Product description',
                    className: 'whatever',
                  },
                ],
                [
                  'core/navigation-link',
                  {
                    placeholder: 'Add link...',
                    label: 'See more',
                    url: `/product/${selectedProductId}`,
                    className: 'whatever',
                  },
                ],
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];

The way I'm retrieving the attributes it's through an apiFetch call:
      apiFetch({ path: `/wc/v3/products/${selectedProductId}` })
        .then((product) => {
          const cleanedDescription = stripHtml(product.description);

          // Set the fetched product data into block attributes
          setAttributes({
            productName: product.name,
            productDescription: cleanedDescription,
            productPrice: product.price,
            productImages: product.images.map((img) => ({ url: img.src })),
            productInjected: true, // Prevents repeated API fetches
          });

          // Replace the InnerBlocks content dynamically with the fetched data
          wp.data.dispatch('core/block-editor').replaceInnerBlocks(
            clientId,
            wp.blocks.createBlocksFromInnerBlocksTemplate(
              createTemplate(
                product.name,
                cleanedDescription,
                product.price,
                product.images.map((img) => ({ url: img.src })),
              ),
            ),
          );

          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          setError(err);
          setLoading(false);
        });

Everything is working properly except the core/gallery block. I assume I'm not formatting the gallery object properly, but there is a lack of documentation about this matter. I'd appreciate any hints.

As a third party plugin Woocommerce is off-topic for this Stack.

This is not a question about WooCommerce but InnerBlocks and Core/Gallery. The topic would be the same for a custom block without using Woo.

The data you're working with is from Woocommerce and answering the question is reliant on familiarity with Woocommerce.

Thanks for your feedback, Chris. I can adapt the question to change the perspective, the data is not about WooCommerce but how to insert images inside a core/gallery. Anyway, the question is answered, if you think this shouldn't be here, I'm happy to remove the question.

It looks like the issue is appearing because we have not passed image id along with the image url, so could you please try to do the same and then take a look.
You can do this by replacing the given code
product.images.map((img) => ({ url: img.src }))
with
product.images.map((img) => ({
 id: img.id,
 url: img.src,
}))

This change will ensures that each image object has both id and url properties, which the core/gallery block expects.

Thanks for your answers, that was what ChatGPT suggested but it didn't work ;)

Well, I got the answer finally. As core/gallery allows the core/image block inside, this would be the solution.
Inside the template, you should run the array of images and create a core/image block for each one:
               [
                  'core/gallery',
                  {
                    images: productImages.map((img) => ({
                      id: img.id,
                      url: img.url,
                    })),
                  },
                  [
                    ...productImages.map((img) => [
                      'core/image',
                      {
                        id: img.id,
                        url: img.url,
                      },
                    ]),
                  ],
                ],

